# MySQL multiple Select?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query on an employees database. I want to return rows where employees wages exceed amount $x

```
SELECT 
    employees_table.employee_id, 
    employees_table.employee_name,
    (SELECT SUM(wages_table.wages)
     FROM wages_table
     WHERE wages_table.employee_id = employees_table.employee_id) AS wages
WHERE wages >= 100"
```

It's returning "unknown column wages"

Comment: seems you missed FROM in query.

Comment: you cannot have table alias(wages) as column in where clause.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT employees_table.employee_id,
  employees_table.employee_name,
  SUM(wages_table.wages) AS wages
FROM employees_tablee
INNER JOIN wages_table ON wages_table.employee_id = employees_table.employee_id
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING SUM(wages_table.wages) >= 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias `wages >= 100` in `WHERE` clause.

I believe you are simply trying to make a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` query. You can then filter by wages using `HAVING` for which an alias is allowed:

```
SELECT 
    e.employee_id, 
    e.employee_name,
    SUM(w.wages) AS wages
FROM wages_table w
JOIN employee_table e ON w.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id
HAVING wages >= 100
```

Comment: HAVING wages >= 100 this has worked just fine. Is it possible to also add HAVING wages >= 100 HAVING wages <= 500 (to create a range)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from (
SELECT employees_table.employee_id, employees_table.employee_name,
        (SELECT SUM(wages_table.wages)
           FROM wages_table
       WHERE wages_table.employee_id = employees_table.employee_id) AS wages
       )tmp where wages>=100
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps to process a query are these

1) From statement

2) Where

3) Select

4) Order By

As you can see, the Where is executed before the Select. Therefore: all aliases defined in the select are not yet available in your Where statement.
A workaround is using an inner select in your From clause that gives you the the employee_id and the sum of its wages. Then you can join them later on and your alias is usable.

Comment: You can also refer to an alias in the HAVING clause, then you don't need a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewrite to:

```
select employees_table.employee_id, employees_table.employee_name, SUM(wages_table.wages)
from employees_table,
     wages_table 
where wages_table.employee_id = employees_table.employee_id
group by employees_table.employee_id, employees_table.employee_name
having SUM(wages_table.wages) >= 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain relationship between wages_table and employees_table.

If one to one relationship :

```
SELECT employees_table.employee_id, employees_table.employee_name, wages_table.wages
FROM wages_table, employees_table
WHERE wages_table.employee_id = employees_table.employee_id
AND wages >= 100
```

If one to many relationship, `GROUP BY` and `SUM(wages_table.wages)` required as other people said.